# Finding a minmuim swaps in an array

Tags: java, algorithm

I have found a problem on a net for generating some sequence.

```
 A = [A1, A2, ..., AN]
and 
where  A1 < A2 < ... < Am > Am+1 > ... > AN for some index m, with m between 1 and N inclusive).
```

I want to find the minimum swaps to accomplish this

For Ex

```
1 8 10 3 7
Swap between 3 and 7 will give me the required seq.
Ans=1
```

I found this code in the editorial:

```
boolean[] done = new boolean[n];
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            int index = -1;
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++) {
                if(!done[j] && (index == -1 || values[j] < values[index]))
                    index = j;
            }

            int left = 0, right = 0;
            for(int j=0;j<index;j++)
                if(!done[j])
                    left++;
            for(int j=index+1;j<n;j++)
                if(!done[j])
                    right++;
            res += Math.min(left, right);
            done[index] = true;
        }
        return res;
```

**I can't understand the code what its doing** 
How can i found the minimum swap ? Is this a standard algorithm question.
And time complexity is O(n^2) is this good.

Comment: Is this some random snippet of code which may or may not do what you want?

Comment: This is a correct code ? but i can't understand it

Answer (score 0):

(Note: swap seems to mean swap of two adjacent elements.)

The idea behind the code is as follows. The minimum element x must be moved either to the first or last position in the array. The number of swaps to move x does not depend on which swaps not involving x are performed. For every valid solution, the swaps not involving x are a solution for the array with x removed. Thus, there exists an optimal solution that moves x to the first or last position and then recursively deals with the remaining elements.

The structure of the code is to find the minimum unprocessed element (inner loop 1; `done[j]` is a flag indicating whether the element at position `j` has been processed), determine how many swaps are needed to move it to the first position (inner loop 2), and determine how many swaps are needed to move it to the last position (inner loop 3). We don't count swaps over processed elements because, when we're moving the current element, those elements already have been moved out of the way.

The running time could be improved to O(n log n) by substituting merge sort for the implicit selection sort and using a Fenwick tree to count the number of unprocessed elements in a range.

Comment: would you add an example , picture will be more clear